# YA Book (series?) - Trying to find a SF story about a young girl raised by a robot on an alien world?

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult

I was at a **Science Fiction Convention** in February and at a panel a writer was talking about **Young Adult Genre** crossing over into **SF Genre** with the focus on *identity*.

Since that is a common theme in YA books he brought up a book that he mentioned 'might not be in print any longer' so as it sounded very interesting I had made note of it, but somewhere along the line I lost the info.

**In this book a young girl raised by a robot on an alien world and while she saw herself as human something had happened to her (** I think the robot might have used some kind of re-engineering on her so she could survive on the planet or perhaps she was disfigured or maybe she's not human, I'm not really sure **) so that she didn't look human.**

As a result she was never allowed to look at herself in a mirror, or something, so when other humans finally found her it was hard for them to see her as human, ergo the *identity* aspect of the book: What makes one human? Is she human if she believes she is?

A few other details that I recall: *She lived in a harsh world, everyone else in her group or settlement or whatever was dead and I had the impression they may have lived in a cave or something (though that could be wrong).*

Now I never read this book and am not sure if I'm explaining it very well, I'm not even sure if it's from the 50's 60's 70's or 80's but I don't think it's more recent then that, so I hold no real belief that I can find the answer to **WHAT IS THIS BOOK?** even here...

Still I thought I might give it a shot as the story sounded very interested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Keeper Of The Isis Light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Keeper_of_the_Isis_Light) by Monica Hughes.
After her parents died when she was a baby, her guardian robot genetically modified her so that she could live in the uplands of the planet Isis, where radiation levels were high. She developed lizard-like skin.

Comment: by Crom this sounds like the exact book (and it IS part of a series). Thank you kindly sueelleker and may I also say "Good Show Sir"